# Conditional Action in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, iif-function, iif

I want my textbox to have an action ONLY if the condition is true, otherwise no action. This is what I have as my current action expression for going to another report:

```
=IIf(Fields!MyTextbox.Value = "0", "Report2","")
```

This does not produce my desired result. It gives the textbox an action regardless of the condition result. Is there a 'No Action' or 'Cancel Action' value?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The null keyword in VB is `Nothing`:

```
=IIf(Fields!MyTextbox.Value = "0", "Report2", Nothing)
```